# Generic "identifier" pattern in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-alias

CUrrently in the process of finally learning C#. But after using C++ and python this is one thing that keeps striking me while writing C#.

C# doesn't have a similar thing to `typedef` in C++. (Or at least htat's true according to various posts here an other googling results.

Now the first use to "type alias" I can understand (though from experience disagree with - but that's something I can learn to accept).

However there is a different use I've gotten used to a lot, especially after using python for years:
The "Generic" pattern. Where I actually don't care about the type (and say I only care that it can be compared to each other). Now of course a generic class can "do" this, but quite often that is overkill: especially since classes typically have many of those, and they are of little importance to people who USE the class.

An example, say I have a dictionary, which binds "values" to certain "identifiers":

```
System.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<string, double>
```

Would be a logical start. However say in the future, when having a clearer picture of the whole application, I wish to change it up. I notice that for calculations I would actually need decimal values instead of floating point - (or maybe even bignums instead of floating points). I'd have to go over my whole code changing this. 
Similar to the identifier: strings are "easy" but maybe in the future I don't really want to use such bloated structures. Rather I use something that "can be converted from strings and is unique enough" in my class
Or, hey, in a different future I might wish to not use the generic dictionary: rather I implement a custom one for this class specific.

All these things would require me to change code at many different places. Potential bug-heavy, and thus a maintainer would choose not to change it due to maintenance problems.

In other languages I learned this was solved either by "don't caring" (python) - or by allowing a typedef. And always using that typedef, also in other classes.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in C#? Is it generally accepted to use long "lists" of generic variables in your class definition?

```
MyClass<A_KeyType, A_ValueType, B_KeyType, B_ValueType, ContainerType>
```

Seems awkward since not the user, but the maintainer of the class might often know better which to use?

---

As a very simplistic (silly) example

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() { }
    private Systems.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<string, double> Points = new Systems.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<string, double>()
    Public void AddPerson(string studentID, double val) {
        Points.Add(studentID, val)
    }

}
```

getters, maybe changers etc would all have to explicitly refer to `Systems.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<string, double>`, even though maybe in the future a studentID would be a simple numeric value or something else. Also the code "using" this, which "gets" the student ID needs to understand it is a string.

In C++ I would parametrize the student type "under" the my class as:

```
public class MyClass {
    typedef string StudentIDType
    ...
```

Then I would use that explicit type `MyClass.StudentIDType` in all situations.

Comment: Not sure if i understand this right, but to me the whole concept of writing code this way sounds weird. When you write code you should know what it's used for, which data is involved and thus which types you need. There is however something in C# which would come close to what you seem to be looking for. `var your_var = 1`, the `var` _type_ (it isn't actually a type), simply speaking, chooses the right type for you. So you could skip the whole choosing types for your variables.

Comment: Python doesn't really have generics and C++ uses *partial template specialization*, not `typedef` or aliasing to do what you describe.

Comment: *"in the future, when having a clearer picture of the whole application, I wish to change it up"* - sounds like over-architecting to me. There are generics in C#, they will work well for *any* `T`. You can use interfaces, reflection, `Convert`, mapper, whatelseiforgot to achieve type-independency...

Comment: This seems like you are over thinking the maintenance aspect and falling into premature fixes for a problem that doesn't exist. If you have a dictionary whose key and value type are known then expressing them as such will allow the compiler to catch a lot of potential type misuse bugs thus the use of specifying the allowed subtypes for the key,value of the dictionary. If you don't know then you can simply use `object` which is the equivalent of "all types" in C#. If you want to change from one type to another of course you would need to cast it everywhere to the new type...

Comment: In C++ it would be considered a grave error, a capital sin even, to use `typedef` like this: a C macro, instead of an actual type **definition**. `typedef` isn't a type alias, it actually defines a new type. Arbitrarily changing the meaning of a type would lead to a maintenance nightmare

Comment: Are you asking how to properly refactor generics where a type has changed? For example, you had `Dictionary<string,string>` and want to change to `Dictionary<int,string>`?

Comment: @DanielKing Well yes, or at least "prepare code so that this is something that can be done without thinking in the future".

Comment: @paul23 that's what generics themselves are for. A generic method doesn't care about the concrete type apart from certain constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C# doesn't have a similar thing to typedef in C++.

Typedef in C defines a new type. C# has type aliases:

```
using Frob = System.Collections.Dictionary<System.String, System.String>;
...
Frob f = new Frob();
```

But these are *per file*. The named alias is not a member of any namespace or type.

And C# of course allows you to define new types by wrapping old ones:

```
struct MyOpaqueIdentifier
{
  private int id;
  public MyOpaqueIdentifier(int id) { this.id = id; }
  ... now define equality, conversions, etc ...
}
```

> However say in the future, when having a clearer picture of the whole application, I wish to change it up

This is the premature generality error, also known as YAGNI: You Ain't Gonna Need It.  There are infinite ways to design programs to be more general, most of which you will never need. The right way to do it is to think hard about what kinds of generalities you're going to need up front, and design them in from the beginning.

Also, remember that Visual Studio has powerful refactoring tools.

> What is the idiomatic way to do this in C#? Is it generally accepted to use long "lists" of generic variables in your class definition?

C# lets you express generality in several ways:

- base classes -- I can accept anything derived from this class.
- interfaces -- I can accept anything that implements this interface.
- generics -- the type is parameterized by n other types
- generic covariance and contravariance -- a sequence of turtles may be used where a sequence of animals is expected
- generic constraints -- a type argument is constrained to a base type, interface, etc.
- delegates -- needed functionality that consists of a single method (example: compare two Ts for equality) can be passed in as a delegate to that function, rather than requiring an interface, base type, etc.

It sounds to me like you are considering abusing generics; one of the other approaches is typically used.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Class1<int, string>();
        obj.Dictionary.Add(1, "hello");
    }
}

class Class1<Tkey, Tvalue>
{
    public Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems like OP knows how to use generics, they're looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Python way, then use `Dictionary<string, object>`

You will sacrifice performance and may run into a lot of runtime issues at the cost of minimizing code changes.

I really don't see any value in this. The maintainer still has to go to all the places where you have used float and replace all variable and inputs. You are kinda missing the point of using a strongly typed compiled language.

Your best bet is to create a generic class that wraps your functionality

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    Dictionary<string, T> innerDict;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of generics in C#. They are *not* meant to allow for easy refactoring the way your C++ with `typedef` seems prepared for future maintainers to switch the type out. Such a usage seems wrong and, while I don't code in C++, I assume this is less used as a "generic" and more of an "anonymous class" definition. That is to say, you are actually defining a pseudoclass of type `StudentIDType` whose only property is a string value that you can access directly via the "alias". There are such a thing as anonymous classes in C# (see closures) but they are defined as the input for some function. Rather, the C# method of handling the above situation is to properly reify the pseudoclass to be an explicitly declared class. Such an implementation would look like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    // DO NOT EVER DO THIS
    // classes should not contain public classes this is merely the smallest possible example
    public class StudentPoints {
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        public double PointsValue { get; set; }
    }

    private IEnumerable<StudentPoints> StudentPointsList = new List<StudentPoints>();

    public void AddPerson(StudentPoints studentPoints) {
        this.StudentPointsList.Add(studentPoints);
    }
}
```

However, there is an *obvious problem* with the above which should illustrate to you why the anonymous class is a bad idea. The first is that you've abandoned Dictionary for a simpler List/IEnumerable. This means you can't access values by key without "searching the list" (that is you no longer have a hash table implementation). The second is that you *are still bound to change types when refactoring*. Unless you can implicitly convert from one to another of the types you switch out then you will still have to change the constructors you use in your code to create `StudentPoints`. **It is unavoidably true that changing the type of something will require code changes for most if not all references to that object.** This is exactly what the refactoring tools in Visual Studio are built to help with. However, there is a pattern that you can use that is C# and would allow you to at least "reduce" the pain of the transition so that you don't have to find every instance in the code base before it will compile again. That pattern looks like this and utilizes overloads + the `[Obsolete]` parameter to indicate you are moving away from the old type and moving to the new:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Dictionary<int, double> StudentPoints = new Dictionary<int, double>(); //was string, double

    [Obsolete] // unfixed code will call this
    public void AddPerson(string studentId, double val) {
        int studentIdInt;
        if (Int32.TryParse(studentId, out studentIdInt) {
            this.AddPerson(studentIdInt, val);
            return;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(studentId), "string not convertable to int");
    }

    public void AddPerson(int studentId, double val) {
        this.StudentList.Add(studentId, val);
    }
}
```

Now the compiler will *warn* you instead of erroring when you pass a `string` instead. Issues here are that you may now get a runtime error for any `string` that isn't convertable to an `int`, something that would be a compile time error otherwise. Additionally this pattern (overload+obsolete attribute) could be used even with the first "reified" class as a constructor but my point is that you don't *need* to reify the class (in fact its unhelpful). Instead you should understand that **yes, generics should declare their types as specifically as possible** and **yes, there are refactoring patterns that exist so that you can compile your code relatively quickly after changing the type for a generic but it comes with the trade of turning compile time errors into runtime errors**. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it really that bad to have public nested classes? Provided the nested class is somewhat specific to the outer class.

Comment: @paul23, Eric Lippert's answer is the appropriate "how to use (not abuse) generics". This answer is more of an attempt to show you why you shouldn't worry so much about getting bound to a type.

Comment: @grek40, yes because any non-private class should be its own file. The only potential exception I can see is a partial class declaration but even then a desire to express code architecture as closely as possible in file structure would weigh toward making the class its own file. Obviously private classes are fine because they are only used within the class in which they are declared.